# finding missing parent from oracle hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with parent/child relationship. How do I find the missing parent ?

Hierachical table:

```
child          parent
2000698835     2001455376
```

If the parent is not present in the customer table I need to insert it. Here how do I find the missing parent in customer table ?

```
select * from customer where true_gcdb_source_key='2001455376'(which is the parent)
```

the query to get all parents of child
select * from sap_cust_rel_init 
start with child_gcdb_id='2002615591'
connect by child_gcdb_id=prior parent_gcdb_id

```
child_gcdb_id parent_gcdb_id
2002615591  2002554170
2002554170  2002554286
2002554286  2002554081
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554286  2002554081
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554286  2002554081
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554170  2002554286
2002554286  2002554081
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554286  2002554081
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554286  2002554081
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554170  2002554286
2002554286  2002554081
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554286  2002554081
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554081  
2002554286  2002554081
```

this is used to get all parents for that child

if any parents are not present in customer table,i need to insert them

Comment: please detail what you need really

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a hierarchical query here, a simple SQL query should be ok:

```
select c1.true_gcdb_target_key, c1.true_gcdb_source_key 
from customer c1
where not exists
(
  select 1
  from customer c2
  where c2.true_gcdb_target_key = c1.true_gcdb_source_key
);
```

I assumed your child field was `true_gcdb_target_key`. I only search for parent IDs not present as child ID. A hierarchical query is only used when you want hierarchy relationships between rows, in terms of hierarchy level, path, root... Here your table already contains parent and child information.